# How to get telegram bot user registered date via node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

How to get telegram bot user registered date in telegram via node.js?
I couldn't find any method in telegram bot api ref!

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log(msg);
});
```

same as this bot: [Robot Link](https://t.me/getidsbot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there have no way to get this data from Telegram for now :(

Quote from previous */START* message (from the bot you mentioned):

#### How it works

> To quote @Superuser27: Interpolation on known registration dates of certain IDs.
>   The bot just has a large list of Account's IDs and their associated (known) creation dates and compares your id against this list.

#### My account creation date is wrong

> Sure. That is why there is a "~" in front of it cutie. It is just a guess and very often the IDs given out at a time differ very much from each other, resulting in a sheer data mess. So just consider the date as some sort of art.

EDIT:
This message can be found [here](http://t.me/getidsbot?start=idage).