# Get number of users in a Telegram group by date

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

I want to show the growth of a telegram group So I want to be able to get the number of users in a group according to the date.
Is it possible to do so? Or can I calculate it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.

You can find out more information why here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50316894/13502835

If you would like to just get the current count of users at the time of call, you can use [getChatMembersCount](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmemberscount).